# How to convert row of 1s and 0s to a new int column

Tags: pandas, string, binary

I have a pandas dataframe with 30-40 columns, which contain 1 or 0. How to get a new column with Ints equal to the binary number of the correspondent string? For example, the first row should give

```
int('10101',2)
>>> 21
```

| f22 | f43 | f242 | f243 | f244 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can do it mathematically, by creating a Series of powers of 2 based on the width of the DataFrame. Then [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) across the rows:

```
s = pd.Series(reversed([2 ** i for i in range(df.columns.size)]),
              index=df.columns)
df['result'] = df.mul(s, axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
   f22  f43  f242  f243  f244  result
0    1    0     1     0     1      21
1    1    0     1     0     0      20
2    0    0     0     0     1       1
3    1    0     1     0     1      21
4    0    0     0     0     1       1
```

`s` for reference:

```
f22     16
f43      8
f242     4
f243     2
f244     1
dtype: int64
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'f22': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    'f43': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'f242': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    'f243': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'f244': [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
})
```